# How do I copy an array of ANSI strings so that I can get another array of ANSI string

Tags: string, pascal, freepascal

I want to know if there is a function that slices an `Array of AnsiString` and return `Array of AnsiString`. The `Copy` function returns `Array of String`, so I happened to search online for another solution but I couldn't find anything.

Do we have a solution to this?

I'm using Free Pascal.

Comment: Simple to write your own function, no?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That's one way.

Comment: Sorry, I can't quite make sense of your q: what do you want that `Copy` will not do?

Comment: I am not sure about FreePascal, but in Delphi, `Copy` will simply copy (or slice, if you use the right parameters) an `array of X` to another `array of X`. If `X` is `AnsiString`, the result is an `array of AnsiString` too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copy will copy any `array of X` to another `array of X.` If `X` is `AnsiString`, it will copy (or slice) to an `array of AnsiString`.

The following proof project shows that the result is an `array of AnsiString`, as it addresses each individual "character". If the result were a `UnicodeString`, you would see only the first character (e.g. `'One'` would be the single "bytes" `'O'#0'n'#0'e'#0#0#0`, so the loop would stop after the `'O'`).

```
program Project1;

uses
  SysUtils;

type
  TAnsiStringArray = array of AnsiString;

procedure Main;
var
  A, B: TAnsiStringArray;
  I: Integer;
  P: PAnsiChar;
begin
  A := TAnsiStringArray.Create('Zero', 'One', 'Two', 'Three');

  { Plain Copy, nothing special: }
  B := Copy(A, 1, 2);  { Copies 'One' and 'Two' }

  for I := Low(B) to High(B) do
  begin
    P := PAnsiChar(B[I]);
    while P^ <> #0 do
    begin
      Write(P^, '-');
      Inc(P);
    end;
    Writeln;
  end;
end;

begin
  Main;
  Readln;
end.
```

Output:

```
O-n-e-
T-w-o-
```

So there is no need to do anything special. Just use `Copy` as it is.

---

*FPC 3.0.0 on Windows.*